# How to pass a value to javascript callback/clousure as pass-by-value

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I am trying to pass an integer value i to callback, which is not working as expected since **i** is available as reference.

```
for (var i = this.texturesPath.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

var textureIndex = i;


loader.load(baseTexturePath + this.texturesPath[i], function(texture) {

    scope.textures[textureIndex] = texture;
});
```

What is the solution/approach  for this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need an IIFE, so you can "save" the i;

```
for (var i = this.texturesPath.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  (function (index){
    loader.load(baseTexturePath + this.texturesPath[index], function(texture){
      scope.textures[index] = texture;
    })
  })(i)
}
```

Comment: @user3804449  Why did you down vote my answer, I believe is a right answer